# LuaLaTeX: problem with Xy-pic

Tags: luatex, xy-pic

Just running LuaLaTeX on

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xy}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

produces an error,

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2019.7.26)
```

....

```
Package: xy 2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9
 ("C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xypic/xypdf.tex"
 Xy-pic option: PDF driver v.1.7 loaded))

! Package xypdf Error: pdfTeX version 1.40.0 or higher is needed for the xypdf
package with PDF output.

See the xypdf package documentation for explanation.
```

As far as I can see everything is up to date.

Say, XeLaTeX runs without any problems.

Where is the problem?

Comment: The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xypdf.pdf) of `xypdf` states that "The xypdf package works with both TEX and LATEX in the occurrences of pdfTEX, XETEX and ε-TEX with dvipdfm(x) to generate PDF files". So no LuaLaTeX unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to define the pdftex commands xy uses by loading the luatex85 package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{xy}

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

There is no garanty, that it doesn't break anyway if xy expects in more places that pdftex is used ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed this way it starts running but produces an error on the first use of `xymatrix` - says that `\pdfliteral` is an undefined control sequence.

Comment: Then try `\usepackage{luatex85}` instead of the \def-line.

Comment: Wow great, this works! Could you add this to the answer?